# C Program GOTOXY on second screen

Tags: c, windows

The first screen, gotoxy code is working. But in second screen. Nothing happens, like, it does not read the gotoxy code at all. Please enlighten me about the problem.

Here is the 1st screen :

[image]

Here is the 2nd screen :

[image]

Here is the code. I would love to learn more about gotoxy. 
Thank you in advance.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void gotoxy( int column, int line );
int main();
int addProduct();

struct product
{
    int quantity, reorder, i, id;
    char name[20];
    float price;
};

COORD coord = {0, 0};

void gotoxy (int x, int y)
{
coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;

SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

int main()
{
int choice;

        gotoxy(17,5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(17,18);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

    gotoxy(22,8);
    printf("1. Add Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22,10);
    printf("2. Display Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22,12);
    printf("3. Search Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22,14);
    printf("4. Reorder Level of Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22,16);
    printf("5. Update Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22,20);
    printf("Please Enter Your Choice : ");
    scanf(" %d", &choice);

        switch(choice)
            {
            case 1 :    addProduct();
                        break;

            case 2 :    displayProduct();
                        break;

            case 3 :    searchProduct();
                        break;

            case 4 :    reorderProduct();
                        break;

            case 5 :    updateProduct();
                        break;

            default :   printf("Wrong input. Please try again.");
                        system("cls");
                        main();

            }
return (0);
}




int addProduct()
{
    FILE * fp;

    int i=0;
    struct product a;
    system("cls");

    char checker;

    gotoxy(17,5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(17,18);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");



        do
        {


        fp = fopen("inventory.txt","a+t");
        system("cls");

        printf("Enter product ID : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.id);

        printf("Enter product name : ");
        scanf(" %s", a.name);

        printf("Enter product quantity : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.quantity);

        printf("Enter product price : ");
        scanf(" %f", &a.price);

        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
        printf("Record saved!\n\n");

        fclose(fp);

        printf("Do you want to enter new product? Y / N : ");

        scanf(" %c", &checker);
        checker = toupper(checker);

        i++;

        system("cls");
        }
        while(checker=='Y');


        if(checker == 'N')
            {
             main();
            }

        else
            {
            do{
            printf("Do you want to enter new product? Y / N : ");
            scanf(" %c", &checker);
            checker = toupper(checker);
                }while(checker != 'Y' && checker != 'N');

           if(checker == 'Y'){addProduct();}

           if(checker == 'N'){
                                system("cls");
                                main();}

            }

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Dumping a wall of code without further explanation and expecting us to - what? This is no personal tutoring/debugging service. How about using the debugger and find out yourself?

Comment: What do you want to learn about `gotoxy`? It's function which you defined yourself, it calls [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx)